# Best git strategy for adding VCS to complex development/production enviroment

Tags: git, version-control

I'm pretty sure that getting your perspectives would help me a lot with a problem I'm facing when trying to add version control to a complex project.

The question is: How would you deal with the following scenario in terms of a git strategy?

### Update:

In order to clarify the scenario as much as possible, I will describe what we want to achieve instead of what we currently do.

> Adding git to an existing project that has multiple developments going
> on at once, so we should provide *at least* one pre-production server,
> where the customer can test and approve changes or new features.

This was the original post:

> - The project has a production server and a pre-production server.
> - On the pre-production server, several modifications coexist. These are deployed on the production server, each one in its own time.
> - The project currently has no version control, and needs to support multiple developers.
> - The code base on both servers is *(not so)* substantially different.
> - The team is new into git, but there is no problem in adhering to a strategy and sticking to it.
> - The use of git is already decided and implemented for new projects.
>
> Although there is a development server available, many modifications
> are developed directly on the pre-production server. This is not a
> procedurement that I need - or want - to preserve, but if it doesn't
> supose an added problem for version control, I don't mind if it
> continues.

Given this scenario, which git approach would you choose - would you make a branch for each of these developments that would be merged against the pre-production and, after approvement, production branches?  From which branch would you create them? Regardless of the answer to this, wouldn't this lead to frequent merge conflicts? Some developments have a shorter lifecycle and the code is *already* different between the two servers.

Would using forks help in any way? Cherry-picks? Patches?
Can you think of a more elegant way to solve this situation?
If you find that I've left out any relevant information to determine the strategy to follow, please let me know.

Many thanks in advance! I've always learned from the questions others have asked, but this is my first time asking here.

### Edit after further thinking:

What if I create a repository with the production code, with as many branches as developments and a fork with the pre-production code?

In this way, if I start a development in a branch from production, would I be able to merge it with pre-production and, later, with production? Or would the different branches merged in the pre-production fork prevent me from having clean merges?

Comment: You describe what you are currently doing, but not why and what problem it solves. Without that info it's hard to give you guidance. From what you're describing here you could simply have a main branch (which is production) and one or more feature branches that represent the work in progress on the other environments. Forks are just more expensive branches, I don't expect you'd need those.

Comment: I do wonder how you verify your production build works, prior to sending it to the production server. Normally you'd try to keep staging and prod in sync to test your prod build on preprod and then promote or swap the environments. If they're substantially different, that's not possible.

Comment: I'm not think that the way I describe our "workflow" solve any problem at all, @jessehouwing. Also, the reason is no one but legacy: things are doing this way for a long time. We are making an effort and adopt a rational and efficient workflow in projects we can afford it, but there one which is specially sensible and we can't face many changes.

Your proposal is to have a main branch synced with production server, as many branches as developments and no-branch synced with pre-production's server?

Comment: Well, not THAT substantially different, my fault, @jessehouwing . But different enough that no clean merges can be made. At least, with one of the servers.

Comment: What you currently call development or pre-production are just names for different staging areas. Try think of your branches independently and then see which server makes most sense to deploy those things to.

Comment: It doesn't sound like your development server is used substantially different than the pre-production server.

Comment: And if they are really too different or diverged, then you'll probably need to create separate repos. If they are still related enough, branches should work. If branches work, then Forks will too,since a fork is just a branch in another repo with the same ancestry.

Comment: You're so right about the under-use of the dev server, and starting to use it properly it's an option (that I would love). 

Despite this, I still found a problem. I've made the exercise of thinking of the branches independently and I still find equally important deploy in preproduction's and production's servers.

Supose I start a new develop, creating a branch from preproduction's branch. I do the work and merge it. When the development gets approved, if I try to merge it against production branch, it will merge also all the other differences between pre and pro servers, won't it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228357/discussion-between-jessehouwing-and-pelayo).